# un-named theorems in Baby Rudin

Tags: reference-request

## I want to know all unnamed things in Baby Rudin

---

I have some questions about the book--Rudin's 《Principle of Mathematical Analysis》

I want to know some errors/flaws of the book, how can I find them? the third edition.

I want to know some *Appendix* theorems idexes of the book.

Sometimes when I recall theorems, Is Abel Limit Theorem(Named in Alfors's 《Complex Analysis》 Chap-2.25) in Rudin's book? Is XXX theorem in Rudin's book, or is it somewhat has some variation in Rudin's book?

For example, Some of my books names a Dirichlet Criteria for series. That is in Rudin's book, 3.42 without name.

For example, Abel Criteria seems in Excercise 8 without name.

So, do you know a full list of such un-named theorems/excercises index table? Have one done such things?

Answer (score 2):

This site will provide so much help

http://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/ug.hndts/#Rudin